# How to close popup window and redirect the parent window

Tags: javascript, facebook, popupwindow

```
string dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + app_id + "&redirect_uri=" + Server.UrlEncode(my_url) + "&scope=" + permission;
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "key", "window.open('"+dialog_url+"','_parent','');");
```

I use this code for popup permission dialog. When user click allow facebook redirect user to my app in the popup. I need to send code from popup window to parent window then close popup when user click allow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tell me if this is what you are looking for...
Parent Window:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function showFBWindow(){
            url = "allowfbchild.html"
            newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
            if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" OnClick="showFBWindow()" value="Open FB" />

</body>
</html>
```

Child Window(allowfbchild.html) :

```
<html>
<head>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function redirectToFB(){
            window.opener.location.href="http://wwww.facebook.com";
            self.close();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    Allow the user to view FB
    <br/>Are you sure?
    <input type="button" value="Ok" OnClick="redirectToFB()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but when i open the popup. the page is redirect to mypage.html. I use code("window.opener.location.href="http://wwww.facebook.com";) on this page then it say .."Error: Unable to get value of the property 'location': object is null or undefined"

Comment: instead of `window.opener.location.href` you need `window.opener.document.location.href`

Comment: Actually window.focus is function, so "if (window.focus) {}" always will be true

Answer (score 0):

in the parent page write the javascript as below

```
 <script language="Javascript">
     function popitup(url)
     {
      newwindow = window.open(url, "popwin", "width = 320, height = 210,  resizable = no");
      if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
      return false;
      popwin.moveTo(0, 0);
      }
</script>

<a href=""   onclick="return popitup('myapppopup.aspx');return false;">`myapppopup</a>`
```

then in the popup windows add a link to facebook as below

```
<a href="http://wwww.facebook.com"   target="_blank"   onclick="self.close();">facebook </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your parent window:

```
<script language="javascript">

function open_a_window() 
{
    var w = 200;
        var h = 200;
        var left = Number((screen.width/2)-(w/2));
        var tops = Number((screen.height/2)-(h/2));

        window.open("window_to_close.html", '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+tops+', left='+left);

   return false;
}

// opener:
window.onmessage = function (e) {
  if (e.data === 'location') {
    window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');
  }
};

</script>

<input type="button" onclick="return open_a_window();" value="Open New Window/Tab" />
```

This is your child window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="quitBox('quit');">

<h1>The window closer:</h1>

<input type="button" onclick="return quitBox('quit');" value="Close This Window/Tab" /> 


<script language="javascript">

function quitBox(cmd) 
{      
    if (cmd=='quit')    
    {   
       window.opener.postMessage('location', '*');
       window.open(location, '_self').close();    
    }     
    return false;   
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the popup window with a link inside it, simply use click event to call the following function.

window.close();