# Mvc4 paytm integration - close popup windows and redirect to main view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, paytm

I am integrating **paytm** to my site. I have view i.e. `Index`. Currently it is simply a view which contains one button which open popup window.

Here is my view.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "paytm";
}

<style>
    .btn2 {
        background-color: #00b9f5;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
</style>
<h2>paytm</h2>
<button class="btn2" style="font-weight: 600;" onclick="popitup('http://localhost:49569/home/paytmcheckout');">Pay With Paytm</button>
<script>
    function popitup(url) {
        window.open(url, "_blank", "width=700,height=700,scrollbars=yes");
    }
</script>
```

Here is `paytmcheckout` action

```
public ActionResult paytmcheckout()
{            
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("MID", "Some value");
    parameters.Add("CHANNEL_ID", "some value");
    parameters.Add("INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID", "some value");
    parameters.Add("WEBSITE", "some value");
    //parameters.Add("EMAIL", "email value");
    //parameters.Add("MOBILE_NO", "mobile value");
    parameters.Add("CUST_ID", "some value");
    parameters.Add("ORDER_ID", "some value");
    parameters.Add("TXN_AMOUNT", "some value");
    parameters.Add("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost:49569/home/thankyou/"); 
    //This parameter is not mandatory. Use this to pass the callback url dynamically.

    string checksum = paytm.CheckSum.generateCheckSum(merchantKey, parameters);

    string paytmURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction";

    string outputHTML = "<html>";
    outputHTML += "<head>";
    outputHTML += "<title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>";
    outputHTML += "</head>";
    outputHTML += "<body>";
    outputHTML += "<center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>";
    outputHTML += "<form method='post' action='" + paytmURL + "' name='f1'>";
    outputHTML += "<table border='1'>";
    outputHTML += "<tbody>";
    foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
    {
        outputHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='" + key + "' value='" + parameters[key] + "'>";
    }
    outputHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='" + checksum + "'>";
    outputHTML += "</tbody>";
    outputHTML += "</table>";
    outputHTML += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    outputHTML += "document.f1.submit();";
    outputHTML += "</script>";
    outputHTML += "</form>";
    outputHTML += "</body>";
    outputHTML += "</html>";
    Response.Write(outputHTML);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

It simple post some data to paytm. You can find out code here https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_dotNet

When request sent to paytm it work on it and on callback url it send some response. Here in my case I have created one action i.e. `thankyou`. But I want to close the popup windows(which calls from `Index` view) and show response in `Index` view instead of showing `thankyou` view. Currently popup windows is not closing and showing `thankyou` view in it. How can I **close the popup window** and show result in `Index` view? I am not getting how can I implement this.

I want to implement something like this - http://paywithpaytm.com/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main window

```
  <script language="Javascript">
    function popitup(url) {
     newwindow=window.open(url, "_blank", "width=700,height=700,scrollbars=yes");
      if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    }
</script>
```

in child pop up

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    function redirectToFB(){
        window.opener.location.href="http://bla.bla.bla";
        self.close();
    }
   </script>
```

instead of using

```
    return new EmptyResult();
```

use

```
 return View();
```

and in that view file you can code this way

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    (function(){
        window.opener.location.href="http://bla.bla.bla";
        self.close();
    })();
   </script>
```

for more details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5049876/3127813)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you tell how can I do this in my ?

Comment: Thanks. I have added `<script language="Javascript">
    (function(){
        window.opener.location.href="http://bla.bla.bla";
        self.close();
    })();
   </script>` to my `thankyou` view instead of my `paytmcheckout`