# Redirecting to new page after closing popup window

Tags: php, jquery, popup

To add the multiple items to Invoice i am opening pop-up window. Once i add the items, pop-up gets closed and returning to the parent page. But once the pop-up window closes, it should redirect to new page instead of parent page.

Now i am doing like this

In page1.php (parent page)

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="lineitems" id="lineitems" value="Add Line Items" onclick="window.open('add_lineitems.php?order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',  'LineItems','height=500,width=1300,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
```

In add_lineitems.php(popup)
 after adding, i am closing window like this

```
if($l1)
{

echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
}

?>
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Instead of page1.php, i want this to redirect page2.php. How can i mention it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close popup window and redirect the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049171/how-to-close-popup-window-and-redirect-the-parent-window)

Comment: Redirecting to parent window is what i have done, but my question is to redirect to different page/window by closing pop-up

Comment: That is exactly what is showing on the link. So if you change `window.opener.location.href` from the pop up it will change the parent (opener). Please read the link content again.

Comment: My apology. Yes, i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to another page you can used `window.location`.Add below code in your `<script></script>`

```
echo "<script>window.close();
window.opener.location='yourpage.php'; 
</script>";
```